# CSS nested menu auto width doesn't work

Tags: css, menu

I have this nested menu, where everything works fine expect from the third hierarchy level.

I have the code and the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/wvsL9/

If you hover the menu: "PRODUKTER" and then "PRIVAT", you see the problem with the width is not "auto".
I am really stuck here, and I have tried a lot of variations.
Can you find out why it doesn't work as I want?

Thanks in advance

```
#menu, #menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue For BBC W01 Bd';
}

#menu:before,
#menu:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

#menu:after {
    clear: both;
}

#menu {
    zoom:1;
}

#menu li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

#menu li:last-child {
    border: 0;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}


#menu a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px 8px;
    color: #000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#menu li:hover > a {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu li.current-menu-item a{
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

*html #menu li a:hover { /* IE6 only */
    color: #fafafa;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;    
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    margin: 0;
}

#menu ul li {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    display: block;
    border: 0;
    _line-height: 0; /*IE6 only*/
}

#menu ul li:last-child {   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}


#menu ul a {    
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    _height: 10px; /*IE6 only*/
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #fff;
}

#menu ul a:hover {
    background-color: #f60c0c;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    top: -6px;
}

#menu ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
    _margin: 0; /*IE6 only*/    
}

#menu ul ul li{
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    float: none;
}

#menu ul ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 50px;
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:after {
    left: -6px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    border-left: 0;
}

#menu ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-bottom-color: #04acec; 
}

#menu ul ul li:first-child a:hover:after {
    border-right-color: #0299d3; 
    border-bottom-color: transparent;   
}

#menu ul li:last-child > a {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
    border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with `width: auto;` on the correct element. Just add this:

```
#menu ul ul {
    width: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yfSnq/)

Comment: Thought I had tried that... because that is of course the most logic answer... but now it works so I will stop wondering and start be happy now! Thanks =)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
#menu .sub-menu{width:auto; min-width:100%;}
```

Here is example
http://jsfiddle.net/wvsL9/3/